# Call Hierarchy with Integration Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, integration-testing, mstest, code-coverage

I use VS2012 Unit Testing for Integration Tests. My large and sprawling object model is written directly against the SQL database. I know, I know, but that's just how it is. It's not a small project. There are some issues with the design, but we'll move on to the actual question...

Is there a better Test Explorer that allows me to effectively group my tests by SQL Stored Procedure name, the functions that it calls (nested tests), and functions that calls it. As well as showing NCrunch type code coverage.

A trite and horrible, but effective example of some code I've just made up.

```
Stored Procedures: GetUser (@UserID)
                   GetPermissions(@UserID, @Element)
```

Class User:

```
Public Function GetUserFromDb(userId As Integer) As User
    '... sql command etc for GetUser
    FillUserFromReader(myUserInstance, myDataReader)
End Function

Public Shared Function FillUserFromReader(instance As User, r As SqlDataReader)
    instance.ID = CStr(r("ID"))
    instance.Name = CStr(r("Name"))
    instance.Initials = CStr(r("Initials"))
End Function
```

Another class called Permissions...

```
'Returns both permission and user on same row...
Public Function GetPermissionsFromDb(userId As Integer) As UserPermission
    '... sql command for GetPermissions
    'use similar FillPermissionsFromReader as above
    myPermissionsInstance.User = New User()
    User.FillUserFromReader(myPermissions.User, myDataReader)
End Function
```

My tests would look like:

```
<TestCategory("Runs GetUserFromDb"),
 TestCategory("Calls GetUser"),
 TestCategory("Runs User.FillUserFromReader")> 'sproc then .net category
Public Sub GetUserTest()
    Dim u = User.GetUser(1)
    Assert.IsNotNull(u) 'etc
    Assert.IsTrue(u.Name = "Tom")
End Sub

<TestCategory("Calls GetPermissions"),
 TestCategory("Runs Permissions.GetPermissionsFromDb"),
 TestCategory("Runs Permissions.FillPermissionsFromReader")
 TestCategory("Runs GetUserFromDb"),
 TestCategory("Calls GetUser"),
 TestCategory("Runs User.FillUserFromReader")> 'sproc then .net category
Public Sub GetPermissionTest()
    Dim p = Permissions.GetPermissions(1)
    Assert.IsNotNull(p) 'etc
    Assert.IsTrue(p.User.Name = "Tom")
End Sub
```

Can you see what I'm doing here?! And this is a tiny tiny example. When I change a sproc I can quickly find "Calls ..." then run all the tests that use that procedure. It's a mess, is there a better solution (that doesn't involve code restructuring or writing my own test explorer)?

Note: I've intentionally not used the `TestPropertyAttribute` as it doesn't group twice in the Test Explorer. So it'd only show in one of the property "groups".

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2012 quarterly update1 (ref http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-and-team-foundation-server-2012-update-1-now-available.aspx ), we added group by traits support which allows you to group by TestCategory.

In your case, tests can potentially shown in more than one categories (which I believe is what you're looking for!).

HTH
Patrick 
MSFT VS-ALM team.